# Laravel 5.7 php getimageinfo 'failed to open stream: No such file or directory'

Tags: php, laravel, image, laravel-5, file-upload

I am attempting to get the dimensions of an image file that IS successfully uploading to my public/images folder which IS correctly symlinked via Laravel to the storage/public folder. I am using PHP's `getimageinfo` function.

To store the file, I have used the built in `->store('pathtodirectory', 'public')` to save the file to the server, which is working. It correctly returns the path/filename associated with the image, and properly saves the file which I can confirm and view.

However! When I attempt to use the `getimageinfo` function it tells me 'failed to open stream:No such file or directory'. I have attempted to use the `Storage::url`, and the `storage_path` functions to grab a path to the file and pass that into `getimageinfo`. I have attempted to use the Laravel `asset` function as well. Nothing is working.

What am I missing?

**Code:**

```
    $photo = $request->file('image');
    $imageFilePath = $photo->store('images', 'public');
    $imageDimensions = getImageSize(Storage::url($imageFilePath));<--Fails here
```

**My config/filesystems.php:**

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
    ],

],
```

Comment: Please print `Storage::url($imageFilePath)` in logs and check there is any image on this path or not? If image exists then check it has permission or not?

Comment: You're using the 2nd argument in `store` which specifies the disk to store (in this case `public`) to but when retrieving it you're using the default disk which might not be the `public`

Comment: @SahilGupta - I was just about to edit my question to include the clarification that the response I am getting is "failed to open stream: No such file or directory."

How do I print that to the logs?

Comment: @apokryfos - how do I retrieve from the same 'public' place? Whichever option I choose, the path is correct (either the system path to the resource, or what I think is the relative path that Laravel is using... which I have no idea what that is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Gripes first... Laravel's documentation is garbage when you need anything other than the introduction (i.e. actually creating an application). This should not have taken me two days to track down this answer. Which is:

`getImageSize(Storage::disk('public')->path($imageFilePath));`

I wish Laravel would expose in its documentation the callable methods available for a resource.